# Make gmail notify me on new mails

Tags: macos, google-chrome, gmail, notifications

I went to Settings and "New mail notifications on" is selected (there was a text as a link above it, I clicked on it).

However, it doesn't work, i.e., I don't receive any notification on a new mail...Any idea(s)?

Comment: I removed MacBook and added OS X as tags. Do you use google chrome and expect it to perform desktop notifications?

Comment: @bmike correct. I want to be notified when a new mail arrives, without having the tab of gmail open! There is a plugin for it, but I hope I could bypass it....

Comment: chrome://settings/search#notifications <- Copy and paste that into your address bar in a new tab. Click on the highlighted Content Settings button and scroll down to Notifications. Ensure that either "Allow all..." or "Ask..." is enabled, and click Manage Exceptions to ensure that there isn't a line with "gmail" or "mail.google.com" in the URL that's set to Block.

Comment: @tubedogg "Ask..." is set and *https://mail.google.com:443* is set to Allow.

Comment: Go to Gmail and turn notifications off completely. (While you're there, does it say in that block whether notifications are disabled in the browser? I have them disabled through Chrome and it tells me that in Gmail settings.) Close the Gmail tab. Go back to settings and remove the mail.google.com setting.  Navigate back to Gmail, re-enable notifications in settings, and theoretically it should prompt you to decide if you want notifications enabled. Enable them and test again.

Comment: I re-followed the procedure. Same thing as before (since all the steps were the same again). Sorry @tubedogg :/

Comment: Does it say in the Notifications setting block in Gmail if notifications are disabled in the browser?

Comment: When it is in that state, I will get the clickable text that says Make Notifications allowable or something like that @tubedogg, so yes.

Comment: Sorry, I realize my question was unclear. I meant, when you have them enabled in the browser, as we discussed above, does Gmail settings still act as though they are disabled by the browser, by displaying text stating that? I'm just wondering if there's a cookie or setting that we're missing where they're disabled elsewhere in the browser.